# Add 11 hours to datetime2 colum in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a date and time column like this:

[image]

I want to add `Time4 + 11:00 hours = 00:53:27:967 + 11:00:00 = 11:53:27:967`
and then append it to timestamp of `Time1` column to get
`2018-10-19 11:53:27:967`.

Below is the procedure I followed:

```
-- Step 1 Trim the Time1 to display only the date
SELECT time1, time4, LEFT(CAST(Time1 AS DATETIME2), LEN(time1) - 9) AS Time5 
FROM table1
```

And got the this output:

[image]

```
--Step 2 Add Time4 + 11
SELECT time4 + '11:00:00.0000000' AS Time6 
FROM DU_GPSTime_2
```

[image]

I am failing in above step.

Final step looks simple if step 2 is fixed.

```
--Step 3 Combine time5 + time6
SELECT time7 = time5 + time6 
FROM table1
```

[image]

Comment: Above is the attempt and code details, please advise.

Comment: It looks like you are struggling, because you store `Time4` as a string, not as a `time`. People give you answers without realising it, so they can't understand why it doesn't work. You'd better say explicitly in the question what datatypes of each column in your table is.

Comment: @Vladimir I am using datetime as per below code `select *,  Right(cast(Time2 as datetime2),len(time2)-2) as Time4 , Left(cast(Time1 as datetime2),len(time1)-9) as Time5
from table1`

Comment: What is the type of columns `Time1` and `Time4`? Is it `datetime`? Is it `datetime2(7)`? Is it `varchar`?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov bravo, Time4 is varchar(40) and Time1 is Datetime. Not too sure why did this happen, even when I am casting it as datetime2

Comment: `Time4` becomes `varchar`, because it is a result of the `RIGHT` function. Just cast it back to `time` and then use `DATEADD(hour, 11, cast(time4 as time))`

Answer (score 0):

Follow example

```
SELECT Time5,  DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CONVERT(time, Time6)) as Time6, CONCAT(CONVERT (date, Time5),' ',DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CONVERT(time, Time6))) AS Time10 FROM TB_EXEMPLO
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am getting error trying to execute above code  `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` I tried running this code `select dateadd(HOUR, 11, time4) as time_added, time1 as curr_date  from table1`

Comment: select dateadd(HOUR, 11, time1) as time4, time1

Comment: sorry it didnt work. I want to add 11 to time4 column not time1 and then use date of TIme1 and time from tim4 to make a new column. Can you please check my screenshots?

Comment: SELECT getdate() as Time1,  DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CONVERT(time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )) as Time4, CONCAT(CONVERT (date, GETDATE()),' ',DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CONVERT(time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ))) AS Time5

Comment: I think you are trying to get current date and time, however I already have date as per the time4 and time1 column, I want to execute it on the date and time i already have

Comment: I'm just sending an example, just replace it in the right place that will work

Comment: If it gets easier this way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189637/discussion-between-duffer-and-rysahara).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a combination of DATEADD and DATEDIFF

```
DATEADD( hh, 11, DATEADD( ms, DATEDIFF( ms, 0, Time4), Time1))
```

Comment: I am getting error trying to execute above code  `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: You have invalid values in your columns. Correct them or use `TRY_CAST()` or `TRY_CONVERT()`

Comment: Not too sure what did i do incorrectly, but i got error **'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.** I used the following code `select try_convert(dateadd(HOUR, 11, time1)as datetime2) as time4, time1 from table1` and `select try_cast(dateadd(HOUR, 11, time1)as datetime2) as time4, time1 from table1`

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using SQL Server 2008 and TRY_CONVERT is not available. You could find problematic values using `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ISDATE(Time4) = 0` (Replace the table name to the correct one)

Comment: Its displaying all the rows of the table, dont why its it doing that none of the values for time4 is 0, it is 00:53:28xxx